# Azure Unable to create ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create an ARM Template in Azure to build VM's and WebApps in prep for the AZ204 exam.

However, I am running into an issue in creating a template, from a downloaded json file.

The error I am getting is

> The client 'Simon.Price@xxx' with object id 'f65d2b21-aa7e-4d5a-9ed3-xxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Gallery/register/action' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Gallery' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I have confirmed that in Azure AD that my account is an Global Administrator, with the description

> Can manage all aspects of Azure AD and Microsoft services that use Azure AD identities.

which implies I should be able to do this.

What permissions am I missing?

Comment: It's not clear when you're running into an issue.  Can you be more specific, eg is it when you're downloading the template after creating a resource in the Azure Portal or when you're trying to create a new deployment from a template you've gotten from somewhere else.  If it's the later can you list the steps you're taking to deploy the template and include the template file itself (or a link to it if it's large)

Comment: @NickGraham having raised this with MS Support now, it has gone to a second line support. As soon as I get a resolution to this with MS, I will post the answer so that others who may encounter this might have some help.  I will also edit the question shortly to accommodate what youre saying